# A 70-80 TV series predicting Reality TV/Big Brother

Tags: story-identification, tv

A series set in future.

TV is the entertainment for the masses.

3D-TV; camera is a cylindric acrylic tube around the scene.

Sex on screen, with artificial sound enhancement.

Some contestants are placed on an island with cameras.

They break the cameras for privacy, and the real show start when the hidden cameras are switched on instead, a person gets hurt, and the drama is that they believe they are isolated and will not get help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This was live-action?  Where did you see it?

Comment: On Danish TV, sometime in 1968-70 I think. Still remember some scenes.

Comment: If you want to post some information about the answer, please post an answer with that information instead of editing it into your question. Editing the answer into your question breaks the Q&A format of the site so it is not allowed, though you are welcome to post your own answer if you have something to add to the existing answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That would be [The Year of the Sex Olympics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year_of_the_Sex_Olympics)

> The Year of the Sex Olympics is a 1968 television play made by the BBC and first broadcast on BBC2 as part of Theatre 625.
> ...
> Influenced by concerns about overpopulation, the counterculture of the 1960s and the societal effects of television, the play depicts a world of the future where a small elite controls the mass media, keeping the lower classes docile by serving them an endless diet of lowest common denominator programmes and pornography. The play concentrates on an idea the programme controllers have for a new programme that will follow the trials and tribulations of a group of people left to fend for themselves on a remote island. In this respect, the play is often cited as having anticipated the craze for reality television.

Comment: I was 9, when it was aired on BBC, and must have seen it that year or 1 or 2 later on Danish Television I think.
And I still remember scenes. Powerful stuff, theatre can be.

Comment: Whatever the concerns were that led to producing this, their predictions were _spot on_.

Answer (score 4):

I asked our national television (Danmarks Radio) and they have a database of scannings of all program listings between 1925 and 1983

It was aired 31 oct 1969, at 20:00, after the news, followed by a 15minutes story of the making of the school magazine of the royal ballet school, late news, and 50 minutes of a competition for classical conductors. That concluded the 4 hours of television sent that day. Oh, the times have changed.